# Sublime text 2 HTML autocomplete with ">" character

Tags: html, autocomplete, sublimetext2

When using Notepad++, I used to simply type `<div>` (without pressing `tab` or anything) and the software would instantly add the closing tag like this : `<div></div>`, setting the cursor position between the two tags. It appears that Notepad++ simply uses the `>` key to trigger the autocompletion, while I need to press `tab` or using the autocompletion box in Sublime text 2 to make it work.

Is there a way in Sublime text 2 to do the same thing ? I want to trigger the autocompletion simply by closing the opening tag without pressing any other keys.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

In sublime text 2 ..  you can type

```
  <d  and then a enter
```

and you obtain

```
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sublime Text offers a variety of shortcuts. You can also create your own shortcuts!

[On Windows] Preferences > Key Bindings - User 
[On OS X] Sublime Text > Preferences > Key Bindings - User

See here for a tutorial.

http://codezag.com/sublime-text-create-shortcuts-key-bindings/

Comment: Thanks. I read this tutorial before posting my question but I couldn't figure out how to use keybindings to create the custom autocompletion I'm trying to achieve. By googling it I noticed many people asked how to bind autocompletion to the ">" character but they always got answers for the default "tab" or "enter" key so I don't really know how to proceed, let alone coding it by myself. It's my first time with ST2 so I'm not sure where to start with or what the correct syntax would be.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this line in Key Bindings - User :

```
{"keys": [">"], "command": "insert_best_completion"}
```

It works fine with simple tags like `<div>` (which autocompletes to `<div></div>`) but it doesn't work when adding attributes like `<div id="something">` or `<div width="100px">`. In this case ST2 won't write the `>` character so I can't even close the opening tag.

What should I add to make Sublime text "ignore" the attributes and still close the tags wether they have attributes or not ?